# Prefix Image of a TextFormField dissapears after the field is no longer focused

Tags: flutter, dart

The email.png prefix will just dissapear if it loses the focus on the field. I have tried to use prefixIcon and in that case worked but then I can't resize the image if I use prefixIcon.

```
TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    //textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Password'),
                    prefix: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 10, 0),
                                          child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/email.png',
                          width:20,
                          height:20,
                        ),
                    ),

                    hintText: 'Email',
                    hintStyle:  TextStyle(
                          color: HexColor("#1A1A1A").withOpacity(0.2),
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: HexColor("#1A1A1A").withOpacity(0.2)),

                    ),
                  ),
                  validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null, 

                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() => email = val);
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: You can't resize prefixIcon. you can resize textformfield .just wrap inside a container.

Comment: But I dont want the whole textformfield to get smaller, I said that prefixIcon made it work, not that it's what I'm looking for because obviously it's wrong to use icon on an assetImage.

Comment: what you want ? unclear from your question.

Comment: for the prefix assetImage to remain there after the I click on another formfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working because previously i was using my icon widget with `prefix:` property where it should have been the `prefixIcon:` property

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: SizedBox(
      child: Center(
        widthFactor: 0.0,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/email.png',
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I would like to use my own email image

Comment: I have updated the answer. let me know if it's not working.